# first element having the index of 1 instead of 0 in a list of tuples

Tags: python, indexing, tuples

I want my list of tuples to start with index `1` instead of index `0`. Here's an example of what I mean exactly:

```
list=[('Green',45.87), ('Yellow',67.43), ('Red',89.98)]
```

Here is what I want:

```py
list[1]=Green 45.87 
list[2]=Yellow 67.43 
list[3]=Red 89.98.
```

How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Use a dictionary with numerical keys starting at 1?

Comment: easy, `list = [()] + list`. Although I have no idea why you want 1 indexing.

Comment: Why would you want that? In programming you **always** start your index at `0`.

Comment: @tolik518 Depends on the language. R programming, for example, uses 1-based indexing.

Comment: You can't. I mean, you can add a first empty element if you want, or use an '+1', like `list[i+1]`, but the index  **always** starts with 0 (on Python at least)

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes you are right, FORTRAN would also start with 1.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you should stick to language standard.
However, if you really want this 1-indexed lists, then here's some basic code:

```
class List(list):
    def __setitem__(self, id, data):
        super().__setitem__(id - 1, data)
    def __getitem__(self, id):
        return super().__getitem__(id - 1)

sample = List([1, 2, 4, 7])
sample[4] = 3
print(sample[1]) # 1
sample.sort()
print(sample) # 1 2 3 4
```

Here, we basically create another list type and override its set & get methods.
Please note that this may be incompatible with certain algorithms that are based on 0-indexed lists.